# TS2304: Cannot find name ENDPOINT when types.d.ts exports something

Tags: typescript, electron, vite, electron-forge

I have the following `tsconfig.json` in my Electron Forge/Vite project:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

And some type definitions in `src/types.d.ts`:

```js
declare const ENDPOINT: string
declare type Api = {
  getBalance: (userid: string) => number
}
```

My app code in `src/main.ts` automatically detects the definition of `ENDPOINT`, but fails miserably if I use `export type Api` instead of `declare type Api` in `src/types.d.ts`. The error is:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'ENDPOINT'.
```

Please note that the app runs just fine, it's only the typecheck in the IDE that fails. So, my IDE suggests to `import {ENDPOINT} from './types'` but if I do that the `TS2304` error goes away and I get a fatal error from Vite (so I guess at runtime) when the `import` is executed:

```
Binding rvalue (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
```

What's going on? I guess somehow using the `export` keyword removes `types.d.ts` from the typechecker roots and make it a module; but when I later import it, the toolchain is not configured to recognize the `.d.ts` file extension, hence the import fails. Unfortunately these are just my speculation, can't find it in the documentation, and I just discovered it by accident. Why does a single `export` breaks everything?